# How to plot bar graph using matplotlib, 'x' is having values and 'y' in names

Tags: matplotlib

```
id,name,group,year,value
5827 Tokyo Asia 1800 685.000000 
864 Bijapur India 1649 340.000000 
1952 Hangzhou Asia 1661 283.612500 
769 Berlin Europe 1922 3873.090909 
3709 Mumbai India 1979 8342.800000
```

My dataset is above. How to plot the bar graph with name on the y axis and value on x axis
Display name has to appear

psudeo code
`df3 = df(data=df['value'], index=df['name'])

I am able to plot with

`ax = df2.plot.bar( y='value', x='name')`

but how to plot `ax = df2.plot.bar( x='value', y='name')`

Comment: Can you use pandas plotting methods? See here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html

Comment: @JamesDowns as mentioned x is values and yas names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output seems to be a graph with horizontal bars. It is called ['barh'](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html) in pandas.

An example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'name', 'group', 'year', 'value'],
                  data=[[5827, 'Tokyo', 'Asia', 1800, 685.000000],
                        [864, 'Bijapur', 'India', 1649, 340.000000],
                        [1952, 'Hangzhou', 'Asia', 1661, 283.612500],
                        [769, 'Berlin', 'Europe', 1922, 3873.090909],
                        [3709, 'Mumbai', 'India', 1979, 8342.800000]])
df.plot(kind='barh', y='value', x='name', color='crimson')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]